# How to display quiz questions with logic in prompt?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of questions that I need to display in the prompt in order. But the quiz has a logic, questions should be substituted depending on the user's answers. Each question has an ID, and each answer has a question ID that should be next. How can I do that?
Right now my code prints them out one by one. How can I make logic in providing questions?

```js
const questions = [{
    id: "1",
    question: "q1",
    answer_1: {
      text: "a1",
      next_question: "2",
    },
    answer_2: {
      text: "a2",
      next_question: "3",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    question: "q2",
    answer_1: {
      text: "a1",
      next_question: "",
    },
    answer_2: {
      text: "a2",
      next_question: "",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    question: "q3",
    answer_1: {
      text: "a1",
      next_question: "",
    },
    answer_2: {
      text: "a2",
      next_question: "4",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    question: "q4",
    answer_1: {
      text: "a1",
      next_question: "",
    },
    answer_2: {
      text: "a2",
      next_question: "",
    },
  },
];

function quiz(questionList) {
  questionList.forEach((question) => {
    prompt(
      `${question.question}`,
      `${question.answer_1.text} / ${question.answer_2.text}`
    );
  });
}

quiz(questions);
```

Comment: You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find an array entry based on a given condition, in your case the `next_question` id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the function to ask the question based on the question object passed as a parameter, then check the answer to the question and call itself with the next question.

```js
const questions=[{id:"1",question:"q1",answer_1:{text:"a1",next_question:"2"},answer_2:{text:"a2",next_question:"3"}},{id:"2",question:"q2",answer_1:{text:"a1",next_question:""},answer_2:{text:"a2",next_question:""}},{id:"3",question:"q3",answer_1:{text:"a1",next_question:""},answer_2:{text:"a2",next_question:"4"}},{id:"4",question:"q4",answer_1:{text:"a1",next_question:""},answer_2:{text:"a2",next_question:""}}];

function quizQuestion({ question, answer_1, answer_2 }) {
    const answer = prompt(
      `${question}`,
      `${answer_1.text} / ${answer_2.text}`
    );

    let nextQuestion;
    if(answer == answer_1.text){
      nextQuestion = answer_1.next_question;
    } else if (answer == answer_2.text){
      nextQuestion = answer_2.next_question;
    } else {
      alert('Invalid answer')
    }
    
    if(nextQuestion){
      quizQuestion(questions.find(q => q.id == nextQuestion))
    }
}

quizQuestion(questions[0]);
```